# How get ALL cookies by aliexpress, using JAVA URLconnection

Tags: java, cookies, urlconnection

I try to get all cookies which my browser has. I used this code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        URLConnection connection = new URL("https://aliexpress.com/").openConnection();
        List<String> cookies = connection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
        System.out.println(cookies.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But the browser has:

```
"name": "__utma",
"name": "__utmc",
"name": "__utmz",
"name": "_ga",
"name": "_gid", 
"name": "_hvn_login",  
"name": "_ym_isad",    
"name": "_ym_uid",  
"name": "acs_usuc_t",
"name": "aep_common_f",
"name": "aep_usuc_f",
"name": "aeu_cid",
"name": "ali_apache_id",   
"name": "ali_apache_track",  
"name": "ali_apache_tracktmp",
"name": "ali_beacon_id",  
"name": "cna"
"name": "intl_common_forever",
"name": "intl_locale",
"name": "isg"
"name": "xman_f"
"name": "xman_t",
"name": "xman_us_f",
"name": "_mle_tmp0",
"name": "_uab_collina", 
"name": "_umdata",
"name": "JSESSIONID"
```

While the code returns just

```
[aep_usuc_f=site=rus&b_locale=ru_RU; Expires=Fri, 16 Jul 2027 18:25:05 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.aliexpress.com]
```

How i can get all other cookies? Is this possible?

Comment: It is likely that the cookies in your browser were set by various activity on the site, not just by visiting the homepage in your browser.

Comment: Yes, it is true. But after a simple visit, about 15 appear in the browser.
A little helped to expose the user agent.